# Powershell Backup snap-in in win7

Tags: powershell, snap-in, pssnapin

In Windows 7 32 bit machine I am trying to work with Powershell CMDETS for Backup and restore.

I downloaded iis7.psprov_x86.msi but it says that "Powershell snap in is part of windows operating system."

When I go and see the Turn windows feature on or off I dont see any option for Powershell CMDLETS for Backup and restore.

I have Powershell 4 installed in system and tried with  'import-module webadministration'

Any suggestion will be helpful...

Comment: Which version of IIS7 are you using ? Can you  trie to see if you can navigate to "iis:\" via `cd iis:`

Comment: I am using IIS 7.5 but I dont see IIS folder inside "C:\Program Files (x86)" also Under Control Panel -->Windows Feature--> Turn Windows fearutes on or off --> Internet infomation services--> Web Managment Tools--> IIS Management Scripts and Tools is installed.